# PHP: Clear form entries upon successful submission

Tags: php, forms

I have simple **one page** contact form with the following logic

- If the user hits the send button and an error occurs, show the error and retain form values
- If the user hits the send button and everything is good, show success msg and clear form values

Here's the complete code. I am using `$_POST = array();` to try and clear the values, but doesn't seem to be working.

```
<form id="contact_form" method="POST">
    Name<br/><input type="text" name="name"  value="<?php echo isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : ''; ?>" required><br/>
    Email<br/><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : ''; ?>" required><br/>
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>

<?php 
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        ...

        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers) == TRUE) {          
            $_POST = array();
            echo "Your msg has been sent.";
        }
        else {
            echo "An error occurred while trying to send your message.";
        }
    }
?>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: _I am using $_POST = array();..._ Server variables shouldn't get changed explicitley.. however it is unclear what you are trying to ask

Comment: If the email was sent successfully, clear the form.

Comment: That will prevent the "success" msg from showing.

Comment: Assign $_POST  to another variable then check it... if it was sent do not show

Comment: _use session for this..._ Why should he? @M.Alim

Comment: So just assign the $_POST to something else in place of using `array();`?

Comment: This has nothing todo with sessions @M.Alim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are using post data before checking that it is correct or not, so it will display the data every time. You can put your php code before form and set a flag if it is success then don't print anything in input value attribute.

```
<?php 
$success = false;
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    ...

    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers) == TRUE) {          
        $success = true;
        echo "Your msg has been sent.";
    }
    else {
        echo "An error occurred while trying to send your message.";
    }
}
?>
<form id="contact_form" method="POST">
    Name<br/><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo (!$success) ? $_POST["name"] : ""; ?>" required><br/>
    Email<br/><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["email"]) && (!$success) ? $_POST["email"] : ''; ?>" required><br/>
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```